# Regex for checking these patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have these patterns in the subject of the mail.

```
[!491440]:<some text>
[Support !489434]:<some text>
[SUPPORT !491430]:<some text>
```

What I need:-

To get the number which ever is present in the subject, after the "!" exclamation mark.
I need the number (which can be any number), fetched from the subject (sample subjects provided).

How to identify from the pattern:-

Square bracket "**[**"(some times there is "SUPPORT" or "Support" and a space) followed by the "**!**" then the **number** then Square bracket close "**]:**"

I need the number. Samples provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?i)` case insensitive modifier helps to do a case insensitive match.

```
(?i)\[(?:SUPPORT\s+)?!(\d+)]:
```

Get the number you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qF8kL5/1)

**OR**

You could use [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) to discard the previously matched characters from printing at the final. `(?=]:)` called positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match must be followed by `]:` characters.

```
(?i)\[(?:SUPPORT\s+)?!\K\d+(?=]:)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qF8kL5/2)

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
[SUPPORT !491430]:Message for Netcetera from Answer-4U
[!491440]:<some text>
[Support !489434]:<some text>
[SUPPORT !491430]:<some text>
EOT;
preg_match_all("~(?i)\[(?:SUPPORT\s+)?!\K\d+(?=]:)~", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 491430
            [1] => 491440
            [2] => 489434
            [3] => 491430
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but here, the "Support can be in any case". Please see the edited question

Comment: @Monisha added case insensitive modifier in my regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\[(?:Support\s*)?!(\d+)\]
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.Use `g` and `i` flag.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/29

```
$re = "/\\[(?:Support\\s*)?!(\\d+)\\]/i";
$str = "[!491440]:<some text>\n<some text>[Support !489434]:<some text>\n<some text>[SUPPORT !491430]:<some text>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```